# Use of Moore-Penrose Inverse in Likelihood Computation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, matrix-inverse

I've been running MLE on a mixed-Gaussian model (let's just focus on the multivariate Gaussian case for now). In order to take the inverse of the covariance matrix, I've been using MATLAB's pinv() command, which is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse, $\Sigma^+$. The likelihood is then.

$l(\mu,\Sigma;Y) = (2\pi)^{-n/2} |\Sigma|^{-n/2} \exp\big(-\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{t=1}^T (Y_t - \mu)^\prime \Sigma^{+} (Y_t - \mu)\big)$

What I've been observing are cases where the optimization chooses a very small error variance (or close to singular in the multivariate case), even when no variable is close to being perfectly predicted by the model. In other words, the variances of $(Y - \mu)$ are all of the same order of magnitude, yet the optimization algorithm is still able to blow up the likelihood via $|\Sigma|^{-n/2}$, because $\Sigma^+ << \Sigma^{-1}$.

Is it known that using the MP-Inv is problematic in the computation of the likelihood? Is the what I am saying generally making sense? How would I test this?

Comment: 1. The Moore-Penrose inverse is identical to the "usual" inverse when the usual inverse exists, so $\Sigma^+ << \Sigma^{-1}$ shouldn't occur.  2. Try working with the log of the likelihood function if you're not already; that's more stable, and will give you the same MLE.

Comment: So I am using the MP inverse so handle cases where the covariance matrix is close to singular. My impression was it is suppose to give an accurate approximation when a singularity occurs. However upon running some tests I don't think this holds, at least in MATLAB. Also I am using log-likelihood already

Comment: It's not an approximation, it's its own thing.  What, roughly, is the condition number of your close-to-singular covariance matrix?

Comment: If your matrix is ill-conditioned, you might want to calculate the determinant term using the M-P pseudo-inverse instead of the "original" covariance matrix for consistency and stability (if you're not already).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. So maybe it is ok to use the MP-inv but only with a determinant calculated from MP-inv as well. For the covariance under consideration, RCOND
=  2.133642e-16. EDIT: Also, isn't ill-conditioned and near-singular interchangeable?

Comment: So I found this on another thread. To calculate the pseudo-determinant, take the svd, and then only multiply the non-zero values to get the determinant. Is that what you are referring to? @jbowman

Comment: 1.  Yes, ill-conditioned and near-singular are pretty much interchangeable, I think "ill-conditioned" when I think of "condition number" and how well an algorithm will work, "near singular" when I'm thinking of math, but that's just me.   I take it that $2\times 10^{-16}$ is the ratio of the minimum to maximum eigenvalue?  I'm used to seeing the inverse... if so, that's pretty poor.   You can also truncate the eigenvalues, setting ones below some threshold equal to zero, for numerical stability, but I know little about this approach combined with MLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this are three more fundamental issues here.

1. We *do not need* the Moore-Penrose pseudo-invense (to solve `y' * inv(S) * y`).
2. We *do not need* the determinant of $\Sigma$ (to compute the term `det(S)`).
3. We *do not need* to work with the likelihood directly (to get the MLE -  Log-likelihood is fine too). So instead of using the likelihood as in the question's main body we can use the logarithm of it and  get $\log L = -0.5 y^T S^{-1} y - 0.5 \log(|S|) - 0.5\log(2\pi)n$ (see the section on the Likelihood function of the MVN in the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Likelihood_function) for more details)

In particular, the first two points are due to the fact that $\Sigma$ is positive definite and it can be re-expressed as $\Sigma = LL^T$, i.e. we can work with the Cholesky decomposition of it. The third point allows us to simplify our lives even further by allowing us to avoid any exponentiation procedures.. As such, assuming that our covariance matrix is `S`,  we can:

1. We can make the solution of the system `inv(S)* y` faster by using the Cholesky decomposition - this step can be done implicitly in MATLAB by using the backslash operator `\`, i.e. the first term becomes  `-(1/2)*y'*(S\y)`.
2. Avoid the need to exponentiate these results.
3. Avoid computing the determinant of $\Sigma$ by using the fact that the sum of the logarithms of the diagonal entries of the Cholesky decomposition of a matrix `S` equals half of the logarithm of determinant of matrix `S`. i.e. `0.5 * log(det(S))` and `sum(log(diag(chol(S))))` are equal up to numerical precision (or $0.5\log(|S|)  = \sum_i \log(L_{i,i})$).

A simplified version of the code in MATLAB would be something like:

```
  L = chol(S)';     
  alpha =  (S)\Y; % solves L'*alpha=y 
  logLikelihood = -(1/2)*Y'*alpha - sum(log(diag(L))) - (N/2)*log(2*pi);
```

I hope it is clear that while the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse itself is not problematic, the need to exponentiate any results as well as compute the determinant of a full matrix, make this procedure suboptimal. As a first reference on this matters, I have found Rasmussen and William's  [*Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning*](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/) invaluable. Especially Chapter 5 on *Model Selection and Adaptation of Hyperparameters* has a wealth of information on the computations around Gaussian likelihoods.

As noted by @whuber, there are cases that using the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse might result into an sub-optimal estimator because the influence of certain data-point might be ignored. This can happen if we are dealing with a semi-positive definite covariance matrix $S$. 
A proper fix in that case would be to include a minimal amount of additive noise variation $\sigma_{noise}^2$ such that $S = K_{data} + \sigma_{noise}^2I$. Here, $K_{data}$ is the data-derived original covariance. This is actually how R&W formulate the computation in their book where the noise variance $\sigma_{noise}^2$ is explicitly included as a (hyper-)parameter to optimise.

Comment: These are all good points.  It seems to me, though, that the ultimate problem is that the use of the pseudo-inverse *is* problematic: it allows the solver to hit upon a "solution" that effectively zeros out all data not lying within some proper subspace, so--depending on how the solver works--from that point on, those data no longer play any role in finding the MLE.

Comment: @whuber: That is a valid point! Nevertheless, this will probably happen for degenerate cases; for most cases it should not be a problem (after all $S$ *is* derived from the data so either $S^{-1}$ already exist or the pseudo-inverse is relevant when $S$ is PSD). Moreover, even if *some* data are ignored that is far from a situation as the one described by  the OP where "*no variable is close to being perfectly predicted by the model*". As the OP suggests what kills the current computation is the determinant where using the diagonal of the Cholesky is a well-known efficient technique.

Comment: @whuber: Happier? :) (Probably wrongly, I did not mention $\sigma^2_{noise}$ as to keep the text simpler. Thank you for your observation. +1 to your comment obviously.)